# Create Base64 from uploaded file without saving locally php

Tags: php, file, upload, base64

I need to send a file in base 64 format through a SOAP service. I cannot save the file locally. Is there a way to convert an uploaded file and send it through in one instance, without saving it?

I initially thought it was as easy as:

```
$base64file = base64_encode($_FILES["cv"]["tmp_name"]);
```

But that doesn't seem to be working great.

Comment: What doesn't work with your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are encoding the filename, not the file content.

Use this to open the file and convert it to base64:

```
$base64file = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["cv"]["tmp_name"]));
```

Then you can send it back to the client. Just double check that the Soap server does not double base64 encode the string.

Comment: This always returns an empty string. Is there anything else I might need to do in order to receive the contents of my file?

Comment: I simple debug is to dump the filename `$_FILES["cv"]["tmp_name"]` and see if it exists in the Server filesystem. Another source of information is `$_FILES["cv"]["error"]` value (see http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php for reference)

Comment: that worked perfectly, apparently Contact Form 7 (WP) doesn't allow you to use file_get_contents within the hook. I placed it outside the scope of the function and it worked perfectly. So basically your answer was correct. ;)